# Give an output from image processing as an input of a fuzzy controller in Matlab

Tags: matlab, fuzzy

I get the image through the webcam. Then I want to process the image and calculate the distance to a certain object in the image from the right edge of the image. Subsequently, I want to give this distance as the input to the fuzzy controller.

How can I do this? How can I link the image processing output to the fuzzy controller?

Answer (score 0):

To get distance you need to work with a depth camera or stereo camera or stereo with a projector.

Stereo camera and projector are use to do triangulation. You can have a look to image calibration/rectification.

At the end, you want to compute a disparity map.

Have a look to this to understand more : [Disparity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binocular_disparity)
This article is really nice too : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337323/definition-of-a-disparity-map)

Comment: Can't I use a simple technique like edge detection for this? Further how can I link this image processing output to a fuzzy controller. For example say I'm doing this image processing part in a .m file. Can I give the output of the .m file (the distance calculated) as the input to the fuzzy controller block in the Matlab Simulink?

Comment: Fuzzy can be use as block or as script in matlab directly, so their a way to pass disparity map as input data for sure. I don't know what fuzzy do or how simulink works, sorry.