# What is meant by Disparity Space Images

Tags: computer-vision, disparity-mapping

Can someone explain to me what Disparity Space Image is? How can it be constructed?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607312/difference-between-disparity-map-and-disparity-image-in-stereo-matching

Comment: @BalajiR Is Disparity space image same as disparity image?

Answer (score 3):

First, I don't think the disparity image and disparity space image (DSI) are the same. Actually DSI is kind of matrix store the matching score of each pixels in two scanlines. More about to http://www.cse.psu.edu/~rtc12/CSE486/lecture09.pdf.

Comment: Link only answers are not considered as answers here

Comment: As @Zen mentioned, DSI and disparity map are not the same.

Comment: I elaborate a bit: 
Disparity map is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337323/definition-of-a-disparity-map). On the other hand DSI is a 2D matrix (denoted as S) with S[i, j] being the matching cost between a pixel (j) in the left image and a pixel (i) on the eppilor line in the right image. The [link](http://www.cse.psu.edu/~rtc12/CSE486/lecture09.pdf) by @Zen has nice slides about it.