# What is disparity space image (DSI)

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, stereo-3d, disparity-mapping

What is meant by Disparity Space Image (DSI). I couldn't find a clear definition for it. In some places it is mentioned that DSI and Disparity map are the same (but I disagree), like in here [What is meant by disparity space image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33067476/what-is-meant-by-disparity-space-images). And in some places it is shown as 3D matrix and is represented by C(x, y, d). 
I want to know what exactly is DSI and how to calculate it given two stereo images.?

Comment: http://vision.middlebury.edu/~schar/papers/symcosts-draft.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This print was taken from the free preview of the paper "Disparity-space images and large occlusion stereo" by Stephen S. Intille and Aaron F. Bobick and it perfectly answers your question.

[image]

Comment: So, the DSI for a single scanline results in a 2D matrix (x, disparity) and the disparity space image for the whole image will be a 3D matrix (x, y, disparity).