# numpy best fit line with outliers

Tags: python, numpy

I have a scatter plot of data that mostly fits a line, but with some outliers. I've been using numpy polyfit to fit a line to the data, but it will pick up the outliers and give me the wrong line output:

[image: Line fitting error]

Is there a function out there that will give me the line that has the best fit, not a line fitted to all data points?

Code to reproduce:

```
from numpy.polynomial.polynomial import polyfit
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


y = np.array([72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 39, 33, 33, 40, 41, 41, 41, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 43, 44, 44, 45, 46, 46, 46, 47, 47, 48, 48, 48, 49, 49, 49, 50, 51, 51, 52, 54, 54, 55, 55, 55, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 57, 56, 56, 56, 56, 58, 59, 59, 61, 64, 63, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 65, 65, 65, 66, 73, 73, 69, 72, 72, 71, 71, 71, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 74, 74, 73, 77, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 79, 79, 79, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 81, 81, 82, 84, 85, 85, 86, 86, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 89, 90, 90, 90, 90, 91, 94, 95, 95, 95, 96, 96, 96, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 98, 99, 100, 103, 103, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 105, 105, 105, 106, 106, 106, 108, 107, 110, 111, 111, 111, 112, 112, 112, 112, 113, 113, 113, 113, 114, 114, 114, 115, 116, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 120, 119, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 126, 126, 127, 127, 127, 127, 128, 128, 128, 129, 129, 129, 129, 129, 130, 130, 131, 133, 134, 135, 133, 135, 135, 136, 136, 136, 136, 136, 136, 136, 137, 136, 137, 138, 138, 138, 140, 141, 142, 143, 143, 143, 144, 144, 144, 145, 145, 145, 145, 145, 146, 147, 147, 148, 150, 151, 150, 151, 151, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 153, 153, 153, 154, 155, 157, 158, 158, 159, 159, 159, 159])

x = np.array([25, 26, 28, 29, 35, 36, 38, 39, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 50, 79, 223, 224, 226, 227, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 368, 369, 370, 371, 372, 373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380, 381, 382, 383, 384, 385, 386, 387, 388, 389, 390, 391, 392, 393, 394, 395, 396, 397, 398, 399, 400, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405, 406, 407, 408, 409, 410, 411, 412, 413, 414, 415, 416, 417, 418, 419, 420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425, 426, 427, 428, 429, 430, 431, 432, 433, 434, 435, 436, 437, 438, 439, 440, 441, 442, 443, 444, 445, 446, 447, 448, 449, 450, 451, 452, 453, 454, 455, 456, 457, 458, 459, 460, 461, 462, 463, 464, 465, 466, 467, 468, 469, 470, 471, 472, 473, 474, 475, 476, 477, 478, 479, 480, 481, 482, 483, 484, 485, 486, 487, 488, 489, 490, 491, 492, 493, 494, 495, 496, 497, 498, 499, 500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507])

# Fit with polyfit
b, m = polyfit(x, y, 1)


_ = plt.plot(x, y, 'o', label='Original data', markersize=2)
_ = plt.plot(x, m*x + b, 'r', label='Fitted line')
_ = plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

For the curious, I'm attempting ground plane estimation with [disparity maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337323/what-is-the-definition-of-a-disparity-map).

Comment: If you know which values are the outliers, simply filter them out: `x1=x[x>=200]`, `y1=y[x>=200]`.

Comment: Unfortunatly the data changes so much it would be hard to threshold consistently

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can fit a linear model with the [Huber loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huber_loss), which is robust towards outliers.

Full example using scikit learn:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import HuberRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

y = np.array([72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 39, 33, 33, 40, 41, 41, 41, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 43, 44, 44, 45, 46, 46, 46, 47, 47, 48, 48, 48, 49, 49, 49, 50, 51, 51, 52, 54, 54, 55, 55, 55, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 57, 56, 56, 56, 56, 58, 59, 59, 61, 64, 63, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 65, 65, 65, 66, 73, 73, 69, 72, 72, 71, 71, 71, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 74, 74, 73, 77, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 79, 79, 79, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 81, 81, 82, 84, 85, 85, 86, 86, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 89, 90, 90, 90, 90, 91, 94, 95, 95, 95, 96, 96, 96, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 98, 99, 100, 103, 103, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 105, 105, 105, 106, 106, 106, 108, 107, 110, 111, 111, 111, 112, 112, 112, 112, 113, 113, 113, 113, 114, 114, 114, 115, 116, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 120, 119, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 126, 126, 127, 127, 127, 127, 128, 128, 128, 129, 129, 129, 129, 129, 130, 130, 131, 133, 134, 135, 133, 135, 135, 136, 136, 136, 136, 136, 136, 136, 137, 136, 137, 138, 138, 138, 140, 141, 142, 143, 143, 143, 144, 144, 144, 145, 145, 145, 145, 145, 146, 147, 147, 148, 150, 151, 150, 151, 151, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 153, 153, 153, 154, 155, 157, 158, 158, 159, 159, 159, 159])
x = np.array([25, 26, 28, 29, 35, 36, 38, 39, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 50, 79, 223, 224, 226, 227, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 368, 369, 370, 371, 372, 373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380, 381, 382, 383, 384, 385, 386, 387, 388, 389, 390, 391, 392, 393, 394, 395, 396, 397, 398, 399, 400, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405, 406, 407, 408, 409, 410, 411, 412, 413, 414, 415, 416, 417, 418, 419, 420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425, 426, 427, 428, 429, 430, 431, 432, 433, 434, 435, 436, 437, 438, 439, 440, 441, 442, 443, 444, 445, 446, 447, 448, 449, 450, 451, 452, 453, 454, 455, 456, 457, 458, 459, 460, 461, 462, 463, 464, 465, 466, 467, 468, 469, 470, 471, 472, 473, 474, 475, 476, 477, 478, 479, 480, 481, 482, 483, 484, 485, 486, 487, 488, 489, 490, 491, 492, 493, 494, 495, 496, 497, 498, 499, 500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507])

# standardize    
x_scaler, y_scaler = StandardScaler(), StandardScaler()
x_train = x_scaler.fit_transform(x[..., None])
y_train = y_scaler.fit_transform(y[..., None])

# fit model
model = HuberRegressor(epsilon=1)
model.fit(x_train, y_train.ravel())

# do some predictions
test_x = np.array([25, 600])
predictions = y_scaler.inverse_transform(
    model.predict(x_scaler.transform(test_x[..., None]))
)

# plot
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(test_x, predictions, 'r')
plt.ylim(0, 200)
plt.xlim(0, 550)
plt.savefig('aa.png')
```

Result:

[image]

I also suggest you not to follow the other answer, as it does not always work. In the following example, it would not remove any points, and result in the green line. The solution above returns the red line, as expected.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code you used to display the fitted line?

Answer (score 1):

If the residuals are approximately normally distributed, you can filter outliers based on the Z-Score, which is defined as:

```
z = (x - mean)/std
```

For example:
Convert your data to a DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(y, x))
```

Then you filter the outliers, based on the column mean and standard deviation

```
df = df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df)) < 2.5).all(axis=1)]
```

Usually a point is considered an outlier when the absolute value of its Z-Score > 3, but here you keep only the points with abs(Z-Score) < 2.5

```
# Fit with polyfit
b, m = polyfit(df[1], df[0], 1)


_ = plt.plot(df[1], df[0], 'o', label='Original data', markersize=2)
_ = plt.plot(df[1], m*df[1] + b, 'r', label='Fitted line')
_ = plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]

I found this Z-Score filtering method here: [Detect and exclude outliers in Pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199796/detect-and-exclude-outliers-in-pandas-data-frame)
Edit: Please note that this approach has limitations, since it is a univariate outlier detection method, that is, it only considers one variable a time. Besides, it is very sensitive to extreme outliers, because they shift the mean of the sample and, consequently, the Z-Score. A work-around could be using the Robust Z-Score method, which incorporates the Median Absolute Deviation (MAD) Z-Score.
Articles:
https://medium.com/james-blogs/outliers-make-us-go-mad-univariate-outlier-detection-b3a72f1ea8c7
https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35h.htm

Comment: You have a typo – greater than versus less than – for what z-score indicates an outlier.

Comment: @Chris yes, that's why it takes the absolute value of the z-score into consideration `np.abs(stats.zscore(df)) < 2.5`

Comment: Yes but in your text you state that an outlier has a z-score of less than 3, not greater than.

Comment: This does not always work, because you consider the axes separately. See my answer for an example

Comment: Still not quite right – you missed the first part of the sentence.  Should be something along the lines of "Usually you consider an outlier to have a z-score greater than some threshold, e.g. 3.  Here we keep only points with a z-score <2.5, so higher scores (outliers) are filtered out."